# Basic question about units in range formula

Tags: kinematics, projectile, dimensional-analysis

$$R = \frac {2v_0^2sin \theta cos \theta}{g}$$
velocity is $\frac fs$ and g is $\frac {f}{s^2}$ which would seem to be $\frac fs \times \frac {s^2}{f}$ resulting in $s$ after cancellation, yet the answer is in feet. How does this come about?

Comment: As someone who used to teach physics, I like to understand how students think about it. Did you simply not notice that the speed was squared, or did you think that squaring a physical quantity doesn’t affect its units?

Comment: @Ghoster the later...ignorance, no thinking involved.

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes had students who didn’t raise units to powers at first, so after that I spent extra time explaining how units work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the $^2$ at $v_0^2$.
$v_0^2$ has unit $\frac{f^2}{s^2}$.
So $v_0^2 / g$ has unit $\frac{f^2}{s^2} \times \frac{s^2}{f} = f$,
as it should be.